# Is it recommended to use the older version of hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I wanna build a blockchain on hyperledger fabric. So I found some good repos in version 1 but not in hyperledger fabric version 2.

Would you recommend to use the old version instead of the latest version (2.0)?

Thanks for any recommendation/suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 LTS was released July 2020, this means that Hyperledger Fabric 1.4 LTS will go out of support in April 2021 (ie do not expect any updates or releases to the 1.4 version such as bug/security fixes).

Any new project should start with the latest LTS version which is currently 2.2

Comment: thank you! It makes sense for me.  The thing is, that it's really difficult for me to change the repos...